# Different pages, same content, different data - React

Tags: sql, reactjs, database, typescript

I am making an admin page for my website. I need to be able to display all my data from my database, with each table having its own page, however the pages will in functionality be the same, read data from the database, but they will be for a different table for each page, with different data and different structure.
Sorry if that's hard to read, not sure what the best way to describe it is

Comment: "the pages will in functionality be the same, read the data from the database and __show the relevant fields__ to edit them" ..... "with __different__ data and different structure" ...

Without sufficient context, your question description seems contradictory. Perhaps edit your question to provide examples of your tables as well as examples of the UI end result that you desire.

Is your intent to dynamically render fields on a page based on the datatype of each field?

Comment: So yeah, the ie I would have a page for Users and a page for Tickets which are each different tables in my database, and the page would display all the rows in the table, and allow me to edit them, so the pages look the same, and function the same just for different tables

Comment: I've done this sort of thing before.  You need a configuration object for each table that defines a Render component for each property of the database object.

Comment: If your HTML part is same and data is different then you can create a single component and based on your API call you will show in the UI. Main part is model or the variable in which you will store the value as it is going to act as a glue. So if HTML is same then go with single component. If HTML is different based on some data create multiple component. In case if you find something common make a separate common component.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a function that uses a corresponding table layout based on the window location.

Your directory structure could be as follows:

```
- components
- - tables
- - - index.tsx
- - - TableA.tsx
- - - TableB.tsx
- - - ...
```

You could in `tables/index.tsx` use a component along the lines as:

```
export default function Table() {
  const location = parseLocation()
  let Component
  if (location === 'x') {
    Component = TableA
  }
  else if (location === 'y') {
    Component = TableB
  }
  ...
  return <Component/>
}
```

Then you simply fetch the corresponding data in each Table.

Comment: But they want different data, not different tables

Comment: You say "but they will be for a different table for each page, with different data and different structure." in your question.

Comment: Tabled data usually presented either in from of  an array of arrays or array of objects. In both cases table building can be automated with any amount of columns

Comment: I think now the author has two options to choose from. If the table data is very different it could be beneficial to have different components for each table instead of having one very huge table component (like your suggestion would lead to).

Comment: In my example, the data is then fetched inside TableA or TableB. I would prefer my approach because it enforces a stronger single responsibility principle because data fetching and displaying happen in the same place.

Comment: It is not enforcing single responsibility, because it is already two responsibilities - fetch and store data, and present in in table view. Splitting view from data storage will enforce contract (shape of props), but will not tie component to single data storage, and data storage would be able to use multiple views. In my example data can be provided from any storage, be it parent component with own state, redux store, mobx store or static JSON file. All what table will know about is props that were passed through and how to present said props.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228365/discussion-between-skyy2010-and-ezhikov).

Answer (score 0):

In React universal measure of reusable code is a component. Your app consist of components and a component itself. Your logic usually tied to your components and different pages that you show is also a components.

You can write your *page* once and then, depending on URL load different data. Actual implementation will depend on your data management solution, your router and so on, but this is achievable. If we talk abstractly, it would be something like this:[image]